# Using subobject properties to bind grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a arraylist it contains sub objects named as CurrencyRateType objects It contains a CurrencyRateTypeName property .I need to get CurrencyRateTypeName property to bind the grid.But i 'm getting an error.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField= 'CurrencyRateType.CurrencyRateTypeName' HeaderText="CurrencyRateTypeName">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" /> 
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the datasource of the grid to your arraylist. And then bind the grid for a column as below:

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="CurrencyRateTypeName">
     <itemtemplate>
          <%#Eval("CurrencyRateType.CurrencyRateTypeName")%>
     </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

Thanks, Hope this helps